# Asp Page in nested folder open like new website

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, iis-7.5, subdirectory

Publish old project on asp, not asp.net, on new server with IIS 7.5
Site work correctly, but all pages in nested folders open like new web-application with error.
example: localhost/reports/all_tasks_report.asp

Error - 
[image: Error Message]
help pls.)

Comment: image of [error](http://i60.tinypic.com/25gfcp4.png)

Comment: Unfortunately some of us cannot see your image.  Can you add it to your post please?

Comment: Fixed image attachment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"This type of page is not served" means that Classic ASP is not enabled on your server.  From IIS7 onwards it isn't enabled by default

http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-not-installed-by-default-on-iis

Comment: site working correctly, only pages in subfolder open like new application with error